# Remove some info such as softlinks from the rpm packages on Linux

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Here is a situation that I am currently dealing with.

I provide a rpm package that contains both 32-bit and 64-bit application and can be installed on both modes i.e. on both 64-bit and 32-bit platforms.

As the package contains both applications so, when trying to install the rpm package on 32-bit only Linux machine. It creates soft links for 64-bit application too along with 32-bit application. And during post-install I remove the soft-links for 64-bit application as we can not install it on a 32-bit machine.

Now, The issue arises, as the package is already installed on 32-bit machine and I have removed the soft-links for 64-bit application as a part of post-install but the rpm still contains info for these 64-bit application soft-links and could be seen when queried through the rpm command but in reality these should not be.

So, any one has some idea to query through rpm and remove the extra info for a 32-bit application. And this should be done during installation of the 32-bit package may be in post-install.

Any help/idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Why the strange workarounds? Why not just two packages like normal, the `i386` and `x86_64`?

Comment: couldn't it be a requirement from application/software users?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the soft-links included in the RPM %file listing. Have you considered adding a `%post` script that would create the soft-links rather than "*installing*" the soft links?